# Find File differences using for loop starts with specific string with bash or python

Tags: python, bash, shell, ansible, redhat

I am trying to add Linux machines to ansible host file with automation script. Automation process is;

1- Ansible machine gets Linux vm list which named **LinuxVms.txt** from one of Vmware server.

2- I developed sh file below. It adds servers into the  "[all_linux_host]"  tag ,from **LinuxVms.txt** file. And sh works. **(One time operation)**

**after this process, what I want to do is;**

Vmteam will automatically send the **LinuxVm.txt** list to the ansible server and If the LinuxVm.txt file has new IP address I need to add this IP address to the ansible hosts file, under the **"[all_linux_host]"**  tag.

I am thinking that the,for loop should be work for this. For loop has to control new arrived LinuxVm.txt file and  only **[all_linux_host]** tag **(not all tags in ansible host file)** if there is a differences between file and tag it has to find that differences and add to the **"[all_linux_host]"** tag.

For example
LinuxVms.txt

1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
12.12.12.12

**current, ansible host file**
**/etc/ansible/hosts**.
[test]
8.8.8.8
12.12.12.12
13.13.13.13

[all_linux_hosts]    **## this is the last tag in ansible host file.**.
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2

**after for loop, ansible host file has to be like this**

[test]
8.8.8.8
12.12.12.12
13.13.13.13

[all_linux_hosts]      **## IP address order is not import**.
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
12.12.12.12

Can you help me to develop for loop?

**One time operation**

````
sudo cp /home/vmteam/LinuxVMs.txt /home/xxx
sudo chown xxx: /home/vmteam/LinuxVMs.txt
sudo dos2unix /home/xxx/LinuxVMs.txt
awk '{print $1}' /home/xxx/LinuxVMs.txt >> ansible_host_file  ##file correction
awk '{print $2}' /home/xxx/LinuxVMs.txt >> ansible_host_file  ##file correction
sed -i 's/PublicIp//g'    /home/xxx/ansible_host_file
sed -i 's/-//g' /home/xxx/ansible_host_file
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' /home/xxx/ansible_host_file
sed -i 's/IpAddress1/ /g' /home/xxx/ansible_host_file
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' /home/xxx/ansible_host_file```
````

Comment: The script you are showing are not doing anything at all like what your question tries to describe. Can you show the *actual* input file `/home/vmteam/LinuxVMs.txt` (or take out the `sed` parts which currently don't do anything at all useful)?

Comment: As an aside, repeatedly running `sed -i` on the same file is extremely clumsy and slow. `sed` is a scripting language; you run multiple commands by putting them in the same script. Then you only have to rewrite the file just once. (But probably it would make more sense to inline the `sed` into a pipeline which reads the output from Awk rather than using a file at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way with awk is as given here.

```
awk '
  NR==FNR {a[$1];next}

  $1=="[all_linux_hosts]" {f=1}
  f && ( $1 in a ) { delete a[$1] } 
  
{print} 

  END {
    for (host in a) print host
  }
' LinuxVms.txt /etc/ansible/hosts
[test]  
8.8.8.8         
12.12.12.12   
13.13.13.13

[all_linux_hosts]
1.1.1.1     
2.2.2.2
12.12.12.12
3.3.3.3
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in three stages:

```
ips=$(awk 'NR==FNR { map[$1]=1;next } map[$1]!=1 { print $1 }' <(sed -n '/^$/d;/^\[all_linux_hosts\]/,/^\[.*\]/{/^\[/!p}' ansible_host_file) linuxvms.txt)
```

Firstly generate the list of ip addresses from linuxvms.txt that aren't in /etc/ansible/hosts (under the all_linux_hosts tag, achieved through a sed command) We redirect this into awk along with linuxvm.txt and for the first input (NR==FNR) we create an array of ip addresses called map. For the second input we check each ip address and if it isn't in the map array, we print. The resulting output is read into a variable ips

```
while read ipadd;
do 
   sed "/\[all_linux_hosts\]/a$ipadd" ansible_host_file;
done <<< "$ips"
```

We finally loop on the ip addresses and append the addresses under the line "[all_linux_hosts]" This is slightly different from the original requirement but will have no affect in terms of Ansible execution.

Comment: thank you Raman I will try now. I will let you know